# How to display news feed of facebook profile once we are logged in through Android Application?

Tags: android, facebook, integration, facebook-feed

I want to do a facebook integration in my Android Application. So for that once I click on the Facebook Login, it will ask me to enter my Username and Password of the Facebook. And it works completely.

But I want to do like this: once I click on the Facebook icon and after input my username and password, it will redirect me to the Facebook News Feed Page and once I back to my application, and again pressing the Facebook Login button,it will not ask me my username and Password?

Answer (score 1):

[Heres perfect tutorial for Facebook integration](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

Have you tried doing this using WebView or Facebook API? I found FB API pretty good.

Comment: yeah..but i m not able to understand all the things.. can u plz provide me the source code of sample application??? so i can go through and test it in my appliacation...

Comment: There is source of complete application available on that page. I would provide mines but not at home ATM.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you haven't figured it out yet or someone else ends up in this StackOverflow question, I've made a sample code that properly performs a request to Facebook's Graph API and displays the user's Newsfeed (it even does Pull-to-Refresh) using a custom Adapter and the ViewHolder Pattern. Link can be found [here](https://github.com/the7thgoldrunner/FacebookNewsfeedSample-Android).